# In TableLayout TableRow align button right?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to align a button to the right of a TableRow. Inside the TableRow I have two textviews and a button. The middle textview is hidden when the button is displayed. This is done inside my adapter by setting the textview visibility to gone.

I am not sure what the best approach is to aligning the button to the right when it is displayed.

Here is my Layout file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget28"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:paddingLeft="10sp"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    >
    <TableRow>
    <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textTopLeft"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium">
    </TextView>
      <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textTopRight"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium">
    </TextView>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textBottomLeft"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall">
        </TextView>
        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textBottomRight"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall">
        </TextView>
        <Button
          android:id="@+id/btnSessionResume"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Resume"
          android:visibility="invisible"
          android:layout_marginRight="20px"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        </Button>
    </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
```

The button is in the bottom TableRow.

Here is a screenshot of what the layout currently looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

//use android:layout_span and remove your right margin for you button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget28"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:paddingLeft="10sp"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    >
    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_span="2">
    <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textTopLeft"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium">
    </TextView>
      <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textTopRight"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium">
    </TextView>
    </TableRow>
   <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textBottomLeft"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall">
        </TextView>
        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textBottomRight"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall">
        </TextView>
        <Button
          android:id="@+id/btnSessionResume"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Resume"
          android:visibility="invisible"
          android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        </Button>
    </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can have a relative layout in the table row and then use android:layout_alignParentLeft on the TextViews and android:layout_alignParentRight on the button.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I have tried this but it screws up the textviews on the top row. Any ideas?